# How to Centalized Logs in Magento 2

Tags: magento, amazon-s3, magento2, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

We are using authorize.net and Paypal as payment options in our Magento 2.x. We want to keep separate log files for each payment method. Anyone has any idea how to keep logs in Remote location.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Thankyou I will post in magento.stackexchange.com